# Нужно найти ip поднятого контейнера Докер и открыть файл index.php

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Запустил все  docker-compose up -d, по какому ip просмотреть файл index.php лежащий в /www/hello.dev
Докерфайл:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache-jessie

   RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        curl \
        wget \
        git \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt mbstring mysqli pdo_mysql zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd


RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer


ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/40-custom.ini


WORKDIR /var/www

 CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ./hosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./www:/var/www
            - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
        links:
            - php
    php:
        build: ./images/php
        links:
            - mysql
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www
    mysql:
        image: mysql:8
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю тут надо парсить вывод комманд **ifconfig** или **netstat**

Вот для примера:
Парсинг вывода **ifconfig** (если вы не указываете конкретно на какой IP цепляться серверу)

```
curl http://$(ifconfig eth0| sed -n '2 {s/^.*inet addr:\([0-9.]*\) .*/\1/;p}')/index.php
```

Парсинг вывода **netstat** (если для сервера указали конкретный IP)

```
curl http://$(netstat -pln|grep :80|awk '{print $4}'|awk -F ':' '{print $1}'|head -1)/index.php
```